# The interior of polygon with n sides and decomposed 7 triangles, 4 squares was found to be a planar representation of a graph with 11 ver. Determine n

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

The interior of a polygon with n sides and decomposed into 7 triangles and 4 squares was found to be a planar representation of a graph with 11 vertices. Determine n

I tried drawing various figures with that number of triangles and squares and use the Euler’s formula. But I cannot see any relation between n and the vertices/faces/edges. Any hints to start pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given $V = 11$ vertices in total.  The number of faces is clearly $F = 7 + 4 + 1 = 12$, since $7$ faces are triangular, $4$ are square, and there is one more face for the region outside of the polygon.

All that is left is to count the number of edges.  There are $3$ edges in each triangle, $4$ in each square, and $n$ edges from the original polygon.  But each edge is shared by exactly two faces, so the total number of edges is
$$E = \frac{3(7) + 4(4) + n(1)}{2} = \frac{n+37}{2}.$$
With all of this, now can you apply Euler's formula?  Finally, explicitly construct such a graph to demonstrate that it is in fact possible to meet the criteria of the problem.

Comment: So $n=5$ right? But imagine 2 triangules inside a square, each edge is shared by exactly 2 faces, but arent we counting the same face more than once? And why is $n(1)$ in your formula? Sorry I'm new at planar graphs

Comment: @Afonso Draw a pentagon.  Then add $6$ vertices inside the pentagon.  Now try to draw lines connecting all $11$ vertices so that you have $7$ triangles and $4$ quadrilaterals ("squares").  Remember that in a planar graph, you must also count the "face" that is the region *outside* of the graph--the whole unbounded region of the plane that is not enclosed.  $n(1)$ is simply saying we have $1$ face that has $n$ sides, so this contributes $n$ to the number of edges (before dividing by $2$).

Comment: got it, thank you!